# How to find the bearing and velocity of a boat on a flowing river

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, word-problem

Point A is on the west bank of a river and point C is directly across from it on the east bank. The river is 648.6 meters wide and flows south at 2.45 km/hr. A boat wants to cross the river from point A to point C in 10 minutes. What is the bearing and velocity needed to do so?

Comment: I have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the boat relative to the earth is 3.8196 km/h

Draw a right angled triangle with this side going from West to east, and the velocity 2.45 North to South so they meet at a right angle. The velocity of the boat relative to the river (which is what you need) is the hypotenuse of this triangle, pointing on a bearing of $\arctan\frac{3.8916}{2.45}$. 
I leave it to you to work out the speed of the boat relative to the water.